# A certain regularization and renormalization scheme

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, renormalization, regularization

In a certain lecture of Witten's about some QFT in $1+1$ dimensions, I came across these two statements of regularization and renormalization, which I could not prove,

(1) $\int ^\Lambda \frac{d^2 k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{k^2 + q_i ^2 \vert \sigma \vert ^2}  = - \frac{1}{2\pi} ln \vert q _ i \vert - \frac{1}{2\pi}ln \frac{\vert \sigma\vert}{\mu}$

(..there was an overall $\sum _i q_i$ in the above but I don't think that is germane to the point..)

(2) $\int ^\Lambda \frac{d^2 k}{(2\pi)^2}\frac{1}{k^2 +  \vert \sigma \vert ^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi} (ln \frac{\Lambda}{\mu} - ln \frac{\vert \sigma \vert }{\mu} )$

I tried doing dimensional regularization and Pauli-Villar's (motivated by seeing that $\mu$ which looks like an IR cut-off) but nothing helped me reproduce the above equations.

I would glad if someone can help prove these above two equations.

Comment: The source is apparently pages 24-25 of lecture 12 here http://www.math.ias.edu/QFT/spring/

Comment: @MitchellPorter That surely it is. I didn't link it because I thought the larger context was unnecessary and might even be diversionary from what is probably a "basic" calculation trick that I am unable to see. (very sadly!) May be you can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's just look at the integral 
$$\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\alpha^2}.$$
The other integrals should follow from this one. 
Introduce the Pauli-Villars regulator, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\alpha^2}
&\rightarrow& \int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\alpha^2} - \int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\Lambda^2} \\
&=& (\Lambda^2-\alpha^2)\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{(k^2+\alpha^2)(k^2+\Lambda^2)} \\
&=& (\Lambda^2-\alpha^2)\int_0^1 dx\, \int\frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{(k^2 + \beta^2)^2} \\
&=& (\Lambda^2-\alpha^2)\int_0^1 dx\, \frac{1}{2} \frac{2\pi}{(2\pi)^2}
\int_0^\infty dk^2\,\frac{1}{(k^2 + \beta^2)^2} \\
&=& (\Lambda^2-\alpha^2) \frac{1}{4\pi}
\int_0^1 dx\, \frac{1}{\beta^2} \\
&=& (\Lambda^2-\alpha^2) \frac{1}{4\pi} 
\int_0^1 dx\, \frac{1}{\Lambda^2 - x(\Lambda^2-\alpha^2)} \\
&=& -\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \frac{|\alpha|}{\Lambda}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Where we have combined denominators with the Feynman parameter $x$, with the intermediate variable $\beta^2 = \Lambda^2 - x(\Lambda^2-\alpha^2)$.
Of course, this could also be approached with dimensional regularization with the same result.

*Addendum*: After regularization we must renormalize. 
Using the minimal subtraction prescription we find 
$$\int \frac{d^2k}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{k^2+\alpha^2} 
\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln \frac{|\alpha|}{\mu},$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That does explain much of the claimed equations. But can you explain the appearance of the ``\mu" on the RHS. (..how is that related to the UV cut-off of $\Lambda$ on the LHS?..)

Comment: @user6818: Glad to help. The $\mu$ comes from the renormalization prescription, [minimal subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_subtraction_scheme). We have $\ln |\alpha|/\Lambda \rightarrow \ln |\alpha|/\mu$. Roughly, the divergent part (and only the divergent part) is taken care of by the counterterm and what is left over is some arbitrary mass scale $\mu$.

Comment: I am familiar with the minimal subtraction scheme but in this case its not clear as to in what sense is $ln \frac{\vert \alpha \vert }{\mu}$ non-singular compared to $ln \frac{\vert \alpha \vert }{\Lambda}$ ? (..here I would think that you are subtracting $ln \frac {\mu} {\Lambda}$..) But isn't it a bit odd one had to have an UV cut-off ($\Lambda$) and _also_ do a minimal substraction? (..I would typically think that one would do a minimal subtraction to remove the $\epsilon$ in the dimensional regularization..)

Comment: @user6818: The term with the UV cutoff, $\ln\Lambda$, is totally analogous to the term $1/\epsilon$ in dimensional regularization. We regularize in Pauli-Villars by adding the Pauli-Villars regulator. In dimensional regularization we allow the dimension of spacetime to vary. In either case, after regularization we have divergences that must be renormalized. There are many ways to do this, but the gist of it is that the counterterms are used to absorb the divergences. For the result to make any sense the term $\ln\Lambda$ must be absorbed by the counterterms.

Comment: @user6818: Note that $\mu$ is an arbitrary mass scale so $\ln\frac{|\alpha|}{\mu}$ is not singular for any reasonable choice of $\mu$. For example, we could let $\mu = 100$ GeV.

Comment: How is what you are saying about choosing a particular value of $\mu$ (and hence $ln \frac {\vert \alpha \vert}{\Lambda}$ is non-singular} different from directly choosing a particular value of $\Lambda$ (and never invoking the $\mu$ parameter!). (..that I can choose an explicit value of the $UV$ cut-off - or equivalently of the large Pauli-Villars mass is what I would think _is_ the advantage of Pauli-Villars instead of dimensional regularization where one just can't choose $\epsilon = 0$..)

Comment: @user6818: Be wary of confusing $\mu$ and $\Lambda$. The Pauli-Villars regulator comes from fictitious particles that *must* decouple from the theory. $\Lambda$ can't be small any more than $\epsilon$ can be large. Most QFT texts discuss this. *If $\Lambda$ is in the calculation after renormalization, the calculation has failed.* We do the subtraction (which we have freedom to do with the counterterms) and the mass scale $\Lambda$ is replaced with the mass scale $\mu$. $\mu$ can be small. Typically it is on the order of the phenomena of interest.

Comment: @user6818: When I have some time I will add the calculation using dimensional regularization. Maybe that will help clear things up. You should think of $\ln \Lambda$ morally as $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: I can see your conceptual point about decoupling as to why $\Lambda$ has to be large _but_ at the end of the day did it really matter? - at least in this example? - if you had simply set $\Lambda = 100Gev$ instead of introducing a $\mu$ and setting $\mu = 100Gev$. May be this is too simplistic an example - may be you can tell me of more representative examples where setting a value to $\Lambda$ will actually give wrong answers since in this case the final answer will not see the difference between setting a value to $\Lambda$ or to $\mu$!

Comment: @user6818: It gives a wrong answer here. $\Lambda$ must be taken to infinity. Have a look at the standard QFT texts.

Comment: Okay. I guess what you are saying is that "by definition" one is obliged to take $\Lambda \rightarrow \infty$ limit (the continuum limit!) and hence it becomes obligatory to try to remove that by introducing a new scale.

Comment: @user6818: Yes. Regularization results in the divergent term $\ln \Lambda$ which must be removed by renormalization.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps since your itnegral is logarithmic divergent you could do the following

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{kdk}{k^{2}+a^{2}}\to \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{kdk}{k^{2}+a^{2}}- \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x+b}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x+b} $$

then the integral $$ A=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{kdk}{k^{2}+a^{2}}- \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dk}{k+b}$$ is convergent so we must now regularize

$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x+b} $ which can be made by using Ramanujan's resummation to get $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+b}= -\Psi (b) $ now use the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula